Trying to get the datetime of 12am on last Monday - it always gives me 12pm
I am trying to calculate the Date object of the last Monday at 12 am.
Here is my code:
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.setTime(currentDate)

        Integer dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        if (dayOfWeek > Calendar.MONDAY) {
            Integer daysDifferenceFromMonday = dayOfWeek - Calendar.MONDAY
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -daysDifferenceFromMonday)
        } else if (dayOfWeek < Calendar.MONDAY) {
            // it means that we are on Sunday and we need last sunday
            Integer daysDifferenceFromMonday = 7 - (Calendar.MONDAY - dayOfWeek)
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -daysDifferenceFromMonday)
        }

        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0)
        Date toDate = calendar.getTime()

As you can see, I am setting the hour to 0. But, calendar.getTime() gives me 12:00:00.
Here is the debugger screenshot.

What am I doing wrong? This thing is very strait-forward.

"What am I doing wrong?" - using these outdated classes like Date and Calendar, outdated in Java 8 (10 years ago) - better use classes from the java.time package  -- and posted code is not valid Java ?!?

@user85421 It is valid groovy that uses java.util.Calendar

somehow I must have missed the [tag:groovy] tag ... anyway, adding the missing semicolons (for Java) I cannot reproduce, I get toDate ==> Mon Nov 18 00:00:00 CET 2024 - by the way, how are you seeing the date? The debugger screenshot does not help since stopped before assigning toDate

and maybe using HOUR_OF_DAY is better than HOUR (unless also [re-]setting AM_PM, otherwise you risk it being PM) (( but I would still prefer the newer java.time classes ))

You should be doing something like: LocalDate lastMonday = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));System.out.println("Start of last Monday was: " +lastMonday.atStartOfDay());

@user85421 It didn't stop, where it stopped is simply no in the screenshot.
HOUR_OF_DAY helped.
Thank you

@g00se OOOOHhhhh!!! This is awesome!! Thank you!

There are some related questions, for example In java, what time is the start of the day?

Prefer int over Integer unless you love getting NullPointerException later.

Just in case anyone is interested in the solution.
I ended up doing something like this:
LocalDateTime rangeEnd = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)).atStartOfDay()
LocalDateTime rangeStart = rangeEnd.minusWeeks(1)

[
       from: DateUtils.localDateTimeToDate(rangeStart),
       to: DateUtils.localDateTimeToDate(rangeEnd)
]

Basically, a single line answers the original question :)

This is exactly the right way (+1). Thanks for answering your own question.

Alex, I was going to draw your attention to previousOrSame had you mentioned anything
